# How to save Touchpad Pointer speed settings on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, touchpad

Going to All Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad,
I try to set the "Pointer speed" at "Touchpad" options. That setting works fine at that screen and I can test the touchpad with the new settings, also I can use other screens as well.
But, if I close the settings window the "Pointer speed" setting is reset to the default.

How do I save that setting?

[image: Screen of Mouse & Touchpad]

Comment: Bug Report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1176035

Answer (score 0):

Go to `system setting` > `mouse and touchpad` > click on `touchpad` tab

and there you are to customize pointer speed!

And amazingly you don't have to click save, it will auto save the value. Isn't it more humanly ) 
[image]

Edit:
Additionally you can install `gpointing-device-settings` through software center to handle synclient.

[gpointing-device-settings](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gpointing-device-settings) [image: Install gpointing-device-settings]

Comment: My menu is different than this. But the normal config not working.

Comment: No, it is not more humanly or however you want to call it. It is crap, because you cannot play with it by fear of screwing up.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu 13.04 on Asus U31SD-AH51 and I also experiencing the same problem, ayr_ton.

Temporarily, you can adjust the sensitivity of your trackpad to your liking, then hit the 'x' button to close it.  In my case, it saved the settings.

For the answer above, if only '22lk94k943 only' would read the question and inspect the photo carefully before answering, he would have understood the problem.